# Margin or padding between column and different ItemContainerStyle for group columns

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I was commissioned to make a window according to this design:

[image: Screenshot]

I chose the ListView container for it. How to make textboxes in cells is clear, but not how to implement indents between columns and different colors for rows. Nothing comes to my mind.

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this UI have to sort when the user clicks a heading?

Comment: @Andy, Not mandatory

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a listbox with a grid and columns in the itemtemplate.

Make the header line a separate grid, with matching columns.

If variable widths are necessary on the columns, use Sharedsizegroup to make the columns in your header.

You can then put borders in a row, with columnspan and cornerradius to round them off.

Textboxes declared later in the xaml will get higher z-index and appear on top.

If you want a gap, no problem, you can have a column with nothing in it.

Here's some markup I have to hand which uses this sort of principle. You edit in a separate row, append each item.  So it kind of looks like it's a datagrid but I have fine control over everything and in particular an explicit point to validate.

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">

  ***** Top Grid is headers *************
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkSlateGray"/>
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="A"  />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="B" MinWidth="220"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="C" MinWidth="120"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="D" MinWidth="120"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="E" MinWidth="120"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="F" MinWidth="120"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="G" MinWidth="120"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="NG" 
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           MinWidth="30"
                           />
                <TextBlock Text="Description" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Per" Grid.Column="2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Quantity" Grid.Column="3"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Nett"  Grid.Column="4"/>
                <TextBlock Text="VAT" Grid.Column="5"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Gross"  Grid.Column="6"/>
            </Grid>

 ********** Listbox for rows

            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TransactionLines}"
                     BorderThickness="0">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Height="20">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="D"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="E"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="F"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="G"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="H"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="G"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNettEntry}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="N"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NettPer, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}" 
                                       Grid.Column="2"
                                       Visibility="{Binding IsNettEntry, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}"
                                       Background="LightYellow"
                                       />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding GrossPer, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}" 
                                       Grid.Column="2"
                                       Visibility="{Binding IsNettEntry, Converter={conv:InvertBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                       Background="#D6EAF8"
                                       />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}" Grid.Column="3"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nett, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}"  Grid.Column="4"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding VAT, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}" Grid.Column="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Gross, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}"  Grid.Column="6"/>
                            <Button  Grid.Column="7"
                                     Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveLineCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                     CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                     >
                                <Path Data="{StaticResource Bin}"
                                      Fill="Gray"
                                      Stretch="Uniform"/>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

 ****** Another grid is used to enter a new line.

            <Grid DataContext="{Binding NewLine}">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F2F3F4 "/>
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="D"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="E"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="F"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="G"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="H"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsNettEntry, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                                          Grid.Column="0"
                               PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ToggleButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                               
                               >
                        <ToggleButton.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="G"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="N" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ToggleButton.Style>
                </ToggleButton>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Column="1"
                         x:Name="DescriptionTextBox"
                         />

                <TextBox Text="{Binding NettPer, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}" 
                         Grid.Column="2"
                         Visibility="{Binding IsNettEntry, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}"
                         Background="LightYellow"
                                       >
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <b:SelectAllTextBoxBehavior/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CalculatePerCommand}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding GrossPer, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}" 
                         Grid.Column="2"
                         Visibility="{Binding IsNettEntry, Converter={conv:InvertBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                         Background="#D6EAF8"
                                       >
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <b:SelectAllTextBoxBehavior/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CalculatePerCommand}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBox>

                <TextBox Text="{Binding Quantity}" Grid.Column="3">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <b:SelectAllTextBoxBehavior/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CalculatePerCommand}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nett, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}"  Grid.Column="4"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding VAT, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}" Grid.Column="5"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Gross, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}"  Grid.Column="6"/>
                <Button  Grid.Column="7"
                     Margin="6,2,2,2"
                     Command="{Binding DataContext.AddLineCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     PreviewKeyDown="Button_PreviewKeyDown"
                     PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                     >
                    <TextBlock Text="Add"/>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
```